# Setting a Variable in another class results in an error

Tags: java, class, variables

What I am trying to do is set a value in a variable contained within another class.

this is how I am currently trying to achieve it.

BookingUI Class

```
private void setCarRegNo() 
{
   aBooking.setCarRegNo();
}
```

Booking class

```
public void setCarRegNo(String regNo)
{
    carRegNo = regNo;
}
```

Yet I keep getting an error saying 'setCarRegNo (java.lang.String) in booking cannot be applied to ()

What is it I am doing wrong? Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a `String` into the `setCarRegNo(String )` of Booking class.  The method signature declares that it requires a `String` argument, and your compiler will complain if you dont supply one.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a string into the setCarRegNo() function.
Like this: setCarRegNo("Some string");

Answer (score 1):

In your Booking Class, `setCarRegNo` takes a single parameter of type `String`.

When you call it from `BookingUI`, you are not passing in any parameters.

You need to change BookingUI to something like:

```
private void setCarRegNo() 
{
   aBooking.setCarRegNo("CarRegNo");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass a string to your setter.  change

```
 aBooking.setCarRegNo();
```

to

```
  aBooking.setCarRegNo("the registration number');
```

as a note, you should fully spell out the words of the variables.